# Waiting on a Task with a OnlyOnFaulted Continuation causes an AggregateException

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library, pfx

I have some simple code as a repro:

```
var taskTest = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

}).ContinueWith((Task t) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERR");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(taskTest);
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace);
}
```

However, I'm getting an unexpected TaskCanceledException being thrown in the try catch block (it's in the AggregateException InnerExceptions object).  "A task was canceled".

Why am I getting this exception?  The Continuation for the task never fires, there was no exception generated by it, yet I still get the aggregate exception when waiting....

I'm hoping someone can explain how this makes sense to me :)

Comment: I had exactly the same scenario as you. I think it would have been more elegant and intuitive to just propagate the result of the previous task instead. Throwing a TaskCanceledException was quite surprising...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You're not waiting on a task *with* an OnlyOnFaulted continuation - you're waiting *on* that continuation (returned by `ContinueWith`). The continuation is never going to fire because the original task returned normally, so it's acting as if it were cancelled.

Makes sense to me.

I suspect you want to create the task, add the continuation, but then wait on the *original* task:

```
var taskTest = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

});
taskTest.ContinueWith((Task t) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERR");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: Great explanation, just one comment, in this case it is probably better not to use the Factory.StartNew() method, because the task can start before the continuation is defined. Here I would use new Task() ctor, then set the ContinueWith() and finally call the Start() method. Does it make sense?

Comment: @JorgeFioranelli: Why would it be a problem for the task to start before the continuation is defined? The TPL will handle this with no problems, I believe.

Comment: Not sure, but I believe it is possible that the task throws an exception before the continuation is added, and then the handler won't be called. Am I right?

Comment: @JorgeFioranelli - If the continuation is attached to a completed task, it will execute immediately if the task completed with an exception.  (It will cancel if the task did not fault.)

Comment: If we await the original task, and we finish sooner than its exception handling continuation does, then the application _could_ exit before the exception handler finishes, correct? How might we best avoid that? Await the _continuation_, but without regard for how it completes? `await continuationTask.ContinueWith(task => {});`

Comment: I see that my previous suggestion would not have the intended effect, as `ContinueWith()` does not expect you to pass it a `Task`-returning method, and thus will not await an async error handler. How else might we solve this?

Comment: @Timo: I would suggest asking in a new question, to be honest. (Bear in mind that when this question was asked and answered, async/await wasn't even a thing.)